# How to extract the text without id in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, findby

```
<div class="tax_details">
    <ul class="clearfix">
         <li>
            <p>Total Income</p>
            <span>£33,254.00</span>
         </li>
         <li class="text-center">
            <p>Taxable Income</p>
            <span>£21,054.00</span>
         </li>
         <li class="text-right">
            <p>Tax Due</p>
            <span>£4,210.80</span>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

How to extract Totalincome and Tax Due , Taxable income without id in selenium using findby

Comment: This is a bit similar to [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28716/find-xpath-for-dynamic-numeric-value-in-a-web-page/28802#28802) from the software quality assurance and testing exchange site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using css, you could do it this way given that the total income doesn't have a unique way to get the element:

```
List<WebElement> listItems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("li > span"));
listItems.get(0).getText(); //Total Income
listItems.get(1).getText(); //Taxable Income
listItems.get(2).getText(); //Tax Due
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do use FindElements() to get all the elements then loop through them locally so you don't have to keep hitting the site. Although with only 2 elements it may not be a big deal but nonetheless if in the future the list grows you would already have it.

The following is untested psuedocode but should give you a pretty good idea what I mean:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//div[@class = 'tax_details']/ul");
for(WebElement element : elements) {
    WebElement item = element.findBy(By.Xpath("'./li');
    ... 
    ...
    ...
}
```

The idea is that you'll have all the elements in a list and then you could access the element attributes or build a switch statement or whatever your requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking to target the elements using the visual text clues, you can use XPath, something like:

```
WebElement taxDetails = driver.findElement(By.className("tax_details"));
WebElement totalIncome = taxDetails.findElement(By.xpath(".//li[contains(., 'Total Income')]"));
String totalIncomeAmount = totalIncome.findElement(By.tagName("span")).getText();
```

1. First line retrieves a refecence to the entire block, assuming attribute `class="tax_details"` appears only once on the page.
2. Second line retrieves the line `li`, which contains the text of interest. The leading dot in the XPath expression is vitally important in this case; see the [official documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-).
3. Last line retrieves the amount, which is located in the `span` element of the line of interest.

In real production, you will probably want to extract this into something more usable, perhaps a method that takes the "text of interest" as input.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a Pure xpath statement. You will need three one each for 
eg. "Total Income"

```
/div/[@class"tax_details"]/ul[@class="clearfix"]/li[p/text()="Total Income"]/span/text()
```

to explain the statement

```
[p/text()="Total Income"]
```

causes xpath to limit the returned li elements based on the text of sibling element resulting in only one span node being returned.